# Wordpress. Как получить посты только категории с ID без дочерних категорий?

Tags: wordpress

Получаю посты для категории по ID так

```
$my_post = query_posts('cat='.$cat); // Где $cat это ID нужной категории
```

Но выводятся все посты, включая дочерние категории.
Подскажите, как вывести посты определённой категории, исключив дочерние?

Answer (score 1):

> #### Важно: не используйте query_posts()
>
> `query_posts()` предназначена для самого WordPress и должна использоваться для
>   изменения основного Цикла WordPress, если нужно создать еще одни цикл, то
>   используйте `get_posts()` или `WP_Query`. С версии 3.0 эти функции могут
>   принимать все те же параметры что и `query_posts()`.

Полагаю надо получать как-то так

```
$myPosts = get_posts(array(
    'category'      => $cat,
    'category_name' => $cat_name // Не уверен, что это необходимо
));
```

где

`category` (строка/число) - Из каких категорий выводить записи. Укажите ID категории из которой нужно получить посты или укажите, -3 вместо 3, если нужно получить все записи, кроме записей из категории 3 (исключить категорию). Можно указать несколько ID через запятую ("3,5,12" или "-3,-5,-12"). Массив передавать нельзя.
*По умолчанию: нет*

`category_name` (строка) - посты только из этой категории (указывается название или альтернативное имя(slug) категории).
*По умолчанию: нет*

Более подробно можно посмотреть [здесь](http://wp-kama.ru/function/query_posts#vazhno-ne-ispolzujte-query_posts).

Answer (score 0):

Используйте параметр `category__in` вместо `cat`:

```
$my_post = query_posts('category__in='.$cat);
```